# Inserir automaticamente vídeo do Youtube em uma div

Tags: div, youtube

No site que estou desenvolvendo, tem um elemento `div`, em que ele precisa capturar automaticamente vídeos do YouTube de um canal, ou seja, se o usuário/canal fizer o upload de um vídeo, ele mostrará automaticamente o último vídeo nessa `div`.

Alguém já fez isso? Há algum plugin?

Comment: Sim é possível, verifique neste link https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_feeds#User_Uploaded_Videos

Comment: Parece ser o que preciso, porém vi a mensagem: "Nota: a API de dados do YouTube (v2) foi suspensa oficialmente em 4 de março de 2014. Consulte nossa política de suspensão para mais informações"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionei dessa forma:

### HTML:

```
<div class="videos"></div>
```

### Javascript (com jQuery):

```
$(function() {
    // Baixar URLs do feed do canal
    $.get('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/portadosfundos/uploads?max-results=10&alt=json', function(result) {

        var entries = result.feed.entry;

        for(var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
            var url = entries[i].link[0].href;   

            // Transformar URL de vídeo em URL de embed
            // ANTES: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aDqExWjK49Y&algumacoisaaqui
            // DEPOIS: http://www.youtube.com/embed/aDqExWjK49Y
            url = url.replace('/watch?v=', '/embed/');
            url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('&'));

            // Fazer append dos vídeos
            $('.videos').append('<iframe width="480" height="270" src="' + url + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
        }
    });
});
```

### Explicação:

Basicamente o get baixa um feed de vídeos de um canal (no caso, o Porta dos Fundos). Depois, é feito um loop que pega o URL de cada vídeo, e aplica uma "correção" que o transforma no URL de embed do Youtube. Por fim, é montado o código HTML do embed, que é adicionado ao div "videos".

O motivo da "correção" de URL é que o Youtube não forneceu uma variável apenas com o ID do vídeo no feed. Teria sido bem conveniente nesse caso. =)

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B4hzH/)

Obs: em situações normais eu teria tentado usar o [sistema de oEmbed do Youtube](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/10/oembed-support.html), que fornece um código HTML mais confiável, mas acabei não conseguindo usar direito porque é um request cross-domain, etc. Em todo caso, talvez seja útil para você, dá uma olhada!

Comment: cara eu queria muito fazer isso com o soundcloud usando oEmbed, achei alguns exemplos mas so achei dando append no body uma div com o iframe dentro e nao um append de um html especifico igual ao seu exemplo.